# Display an image created in controller in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm working on a project where I'm generating a svg of a QR code in my controller, I want to then display this svg in my view, but I'm not sure hwo to go about this. I've tried passing the image to and `image_tag()`  but that doesn't seem to work, how do I go about making this work?

Comment: Please show some code. How do you generate that SVG?

Comment: Do you know the route of the saved SVG?

Comment: I've already worked it out, but the SVG isn't saved, it's generated in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do it,

I created a route for the SVG, then in the controller action I generated the SVG and used send_data, this then let me use the route for the url in the image tag.